# Can I show an App Extension with an UIDocumentationInteractionController?

Tags: ios, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-app-extension, uidocumentinteraction

I' using an `UIDocumentationInteractionController` to show all compatible apps which can open the files stored in my app. It has always worked well, however I have noticed that with iOS 8 it shows only the apps and not the App Extensions. In the official documentation I can't find anything about that. Is it a bug or a deliberate thing? Do we need to use the `UIActivityViewController` instead?

Answer (score 1):

As far as IOS 8.1 `UIActivityViewController` is the only extension point for the share & action extensions. so yes, if you wish to allow share extensions you must switch to UIActivityViewController.
You can read about it in this blog post:

http://getnotebox.com/developer/uiactivityviewcontroller-ios-8/

Here is a pretty good guide on using UIActivityViewController:

http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/